# C compiler not found, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-construction, 64-bit, wine

I'm trying to install wine on a 64bits, so I followed this : http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit

And when I launch configure, I have this error :

"configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH"

But the whereis gcc says:

"gcc: /usr/lib/gcc"

What shoud I do now?

Comment: Add the output of $PATH to your question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Ok. I already did this, but probably not in the same folder. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter which folder you run this in.