# C compiler not found, but GCC is installed

Tags: linux, gcc, slackware

I have a fresh install of a Slackware64 14.0 on a dedicate server and I'm having a hard time to compile nginx.

```
./configure (my options)
```

returns

```
checking for OS
 + Linux 3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... not found

./configure: error: C compiler cc is not found
```

but gcc is installed, as this is what `gcc -v` returns:

```
Reading specs from /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.7.1/specs
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.7.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-slackware-linux
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.1/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/man --infodir=/usr/info --enable-shared --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,go,java,lto,objc --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-objc-gc --with-system-zlib --with-python-dir=/lib64/python2.7/site-packages --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libssp --enable-lto --with-gnu-ld --verbose --enable-java-home --with-java-home=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib64/jvm --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib64/jvm/jvm-exports --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-antlr-jar=/home/slackware/slackbuilds/gcc/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar --enable-multilib --target=x86_64-slackware-linux --build=x86_64-slackware-linux --host=x86_64-slackware-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.1 (GCC)
```

**What I tried** (after googling)

"*`/tmp` is mounted with `noexec`.*"
Indeed it was, as part of my hardening configurations. I changed it and reboot to make sure, now my `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md1    /   ext4    errors=remount-ro,discard   0   1
/dev/md2    /home   ext4    defaults,discard    1   2
/dev/md5    /var/www    ext4    defaults,discard    1   2
/dev/md6    /var/log    ext4    defaults,discard    1   2
/dev/md7    /tmp    ext4    defaults,discard,nodev,nosuid   1   2
/dev/md8    /var/lib/mysql  ext4    defaults,discard    1   2
/dev/sda3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sdb3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults        0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults        0       0
/tmp            /var/tmp none   rw,nosuid,nodev,bind    0   0
```

The new fstab without noexec does not work though. (I even tried with explicit `exec`)

"*gcc is not on your `$PATH`*"
It is.

```
whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib64/gcc /usr/X11R6/bin/gcc /usr/bin/X11/gcc /usr/X11/bin/gcc /usr/libexec/gcc /usr/man/man1/gcc.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz /usr/X11/man/man1/gcc.1.gz

echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

**Other things I did:**

Looking nginx configure file, they make use of a CC var. This CC did not exist.

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
```

This did not work too.

I tried compiling another program from source to make sure this is not nginx problem, and I found something interesting maybe:

By trying to compile `htop`, I got this:

```
./configure 

checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/napster/htop-master':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Which is expected, because even though I have a minimal installation without most deveveloper tools, the gcc is found. This error should be solved by installing the required tool.

I even checked symbolic links on `/usr/bin` to make sure gcc and cc are ok:

```
ls -l /usr/bin

cc -> gcc
gcc -> gcc-4.7.1
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if you have the build-essential package installed as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557029/c-compiler-not-found-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the contents of the 'config.log' file?

Most likely you're picking up some bad CFLAGS or LDFLAGS somewhere -- possibly in the config script or from nginx/htop defaults.

CFLAGS and LDFLAGS are options passed to the compiler's command line. If they're invalid then the compiler won't run.

The same symptom could result if you're missing a basic library that nginx/htop needs and the LDFLAG that specifies that is causing gcc to bail out.

You really need to check the config.log file.

Comment: Even though the errors were different, the cause was the same. Solving the error pointed out on config.log also solved nginx one. Thanks.

Comment: In case someone else is wondering, the config.log from htop for me pointed out I was missing libmpc.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this, the problem was that I had specified the build directory as `--builddir=~/git/nginx/build`.

After seeing the error, I looked in the file `~/git/nginx/build/autoconf.err` and saw the message:

```
cc1: fatal error: /home/aaron/git/nginx/build/autotest.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This seemed strange. Then I noticed a rogue directory, named `~`, had appeared!

A quick `rm -fr \~/` got rid of it, and then I ran `auto/configure` again but with an absolute path for `--builddir` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `--with-cc` option to configure.

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html for details.

Answer (score -3):

I think maybe it is the permission problem. 
I use sudo ./configure it will be OK.